# minio A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I'm trying to move object on MinIO yet running into weird issue (even though I'm able to move other objects fine without any issues)

summary:

> mc:  Failed to copy `https://FQDN/path1/file.txt`. A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented

details:

```
alexus@mba ~ % uname -a
Darwin mba.local 22.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Thu Jun  8 22:21:34 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.3~7/RELEASE_ARM64_T8112 arm64
alexus@mba ~ % mc --version
mc version RELEASE.2023-08-08T17-23-59Z (commit-id=01fb7c5a96ccc8bab434d1210847279710c8ae93)
Runtime: go1.19.12 darwin/arm64
Copyright (c) 2015-2023 MinIO, Inc.
License GNU AGPLv3 <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html>
alexus@mba ~ % mc mv alias/path1/file.txt alias/path2/
mc: <ERROR> Failed to copy `https://FQDN/path1/file.txt`. A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented
alexus@mba ~ % echo $?
1
alexus@mba ~ %
```

`with --debug`:

```
mc: <DEBUG> PUT /path/file.txt?partNumber=1&uploadId=0e9f9361-9cf2-449f-b891-22a642ffb94c HTTP/1.1
Host: minio.regemini.io
User-Agent: MinIO (darwin; arm64) minio-go/v7.0.61 mc/RELEASE.2023-08-08T17-23-59Z
Content-Length: 0
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XYZ/20230810/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-copy-source;x-amz-copy-source-range;x-amz-date, Signature=**REDACTED**
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
X-Amz-Copy-Source: /path/file.txt
X-Amz-Copy-Source-Range: bytes=0-245457489
X-Amz-Date: 20230810T193116Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip

mc: <DEBUG> HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Content-Length: 604
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Thu, 10 Aug 2023 19:31:16 GMT
Server: istio-envoy
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Origin
X-Amz-Request-Id: 177A1C6FBF94464C
X-Envoy-Upstream-Service-Time: 47
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Please advise.